# DotNetNuke tutorial source

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am currently learning how to develop a module for dotNetNke and I'm watching some videos on dnnsoftware.com.
I am going through the 31 videos under the "Development" category but I did not find the sources of the module developed in the video.

Does Chris Hammond or someone else can help me find the sources?

2nd question: The tutorial was made for DNN 6. Will there be a video tutorial for module development on dnn7? Or at least, is there a wiki page to show the main differences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dnntaskmanager.codeplex.com has the source code.

The tutorial was actually made for DNN5 if I recall, but you can use the source for DNN7. There is updated source for DNN7 modules on that codeplex project, I just haven't had time to do new tutorials yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't wait to see the updated tutorial with the brand new DAL2.

Comment: I hope to get to it in September, but we'll see. I have a lot of paying projects that are taking up my evenings right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the videos of  http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/ . And also in www.dnnhero.com you can learn how to develop dnn 7.x modules with the Christoc Templates.